# HDMI 4K not working with Intel HD

Tags: 14.04, resolution, intel-graphics, hdmi

Under Ubuntu 14.04 the maximum resolution provided when my Samsung Series 7 Ultra is connected to a Sony UHD TV, is 1080p. I tried to add various mode lines with different refresh rates and updated to the latest Intel drivers but, if the resolution is going to be changed to now available UHD over the Ubuntu settings, nothing happens except the graphical output gets messed up for a few seconds.

Is there any other solution attempts other than testing modelines?